# Grails API Update (PUT) without an ID

Tags: json, api, grails, curl, http-put

I'm working on an API for my Grails application and am trying to do something somewhat non-REST (though quite useful).  I am trying to allow the Show and Update actions to accept either ID **or** name.  I have the following mappings in my URLMappings file:

```
"/api/host" (controller:"API", action:"hostList", method:'GET', parseRequest:true)
"/api/host/$id" (controller:"API", action:"hostShow", method:'GET', parseRequest:true)
"/api/host/$id" (controller:"API", action:"hostUpdate", method:'PUT', parseRequest:true)   
"/api/host" (controller:"API", action:"hostCreate", method:'POST', parseRequest:true)
```

What I want is to have the hostShow and hostUpdate controller actions accept either ID **or** name as $id.  This is working fine with the Show action, but when I try it with HTTP-PUT, I get the following error:

```
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8   
{"errors":[{"object":"Host","field":"id","rejected-value":"TEST","message":"Property id must be a valid number"}]}
```

I can't seem to get around this error.  The CURL command I am using to try and perform this is:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{name:NEWTEST}", http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/host/TEST
```

Any feedback or help with this would be very much appreciated!  Below is the code for my hostShow and hostUpdate actions:

```
def hostShow() {
    def hostInstance
    try {
        hostInstance = Host.get(params.id)
    }
    catch(Exception E) {
        hostInstance = Host.findByHostname(params.id)
    }

    if(hostInstance == null)
        respond null, [status: HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND]

    respond hostInstance
}    

@Transactional
def hostUpdate() {
    // Convert incoming JSON to params structure
    request.JSON.each { k,v ->
        params[k] = v
    }    

    // Get by either ID or hostname
    def hostInstance
    try {
        hostInstance = Host.get(params.id)
    }
    catch(Exception E) {
        hostInstance = Host.findByHostname(params.id)
    }

    hostInstance.properties = params   // Set new properties
    hostInstance.save(flush:true)                 

    respond hostInstance, [status: HttpStatus.OK]
}
```

Comment: *trying to do something somewhat non-REST* -- Why?

Comment: Because IDs are internal to the application and not used by those who will be leveraging the API.  We need to have the API operate on object name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with the code that was giving me the error, NOT a problem with Grails or the API mechanism itself.

The issue was that when I set hostInstance.properties=params, it tries to set the hostInstance.id to params.id, which in this case is the hostname.  I solved this be adding the line:

```
params.id = hostInstance.id   // <--- This line solves the problem
hostInstance.properties=params
```

Thanks for the feedback and sorry for asking a question with such a simple bug (in retrospect).